# Reset password confirmation does not work properly?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

It works if i put it like that where user_id = 3 or when i remove the where statement(WHERE user_id=".$user['user_id'].") but then all my password in the db change.

I used get method to get the userid like that
user_id=3&reset_token=xxxxxxxxx

```
<?php

if( isset($_GET['user_id']) && isset($_GET['reset_token']) ) {
$userid = $_GET['user_id']; 
$reset_token = $_GET['reset_token']; 

// Make sure user email with matching hash exist
$req = $heidisql->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id='$userid' AND reset_token='$reset_token' ");

$req->execute($userid, $reset_token );

$user = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


    if ($user) {

       if (!preg_match ('%\A(?=[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*?[A-Z])(?=[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*?[a-z])(?=[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*?[0-9])\S{8,30}\z%', $_POST['new_pass']) 
         || $_POST['new_pass'] !== $_POST['confirm_newpass'] ) {

       echo 'Your new password did not match the new confirm password or is invalid!';
       exit();

        } 

   } 

  } else {

        $newpassword = escape_data($_POST['new_pass']);
        $newpass_hash = password_hash($newpassword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

        $sql= "UPDATE users SET "
                . "password_hashcode='$newpass_hash', "
                . "reset_allocated_time=NULL, "
                . "reset_token=NULL "
                . "WHERE user_id=".$user['user_id']." "; //<- error here

        // Make sure user email with matching hash exist
        $result_newpass = $heidisql->prepare($sql);

        $result_newpass->execute();

        echo "Your password has been reset!";

        exit();

    }
```

already try user_id = '$userid'/ $_GET['user_id']
So, how should i define the variable user_id?

Still does not work
      $req = $heidisql->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=':user_id' AND reset_token=':reset_token' ");

```
   $req->execute([':user_id'=>$userid, ':reset_token'=>$reset_token]);

   $sql= "UPDATE users SET password_hashcode=':password_hashcode', reset_allocated_time=NULL, reset_token=NULL WHERE user_id=:user_id";
   $result_newpass = $heidisql->prepare($sql); $result_newpass->execute([':user_id'=>$userid,':password_hashcode'=>$newpass_hash, ':reset_token'=>NULL, ':reset_allocated_time'=>NULL]);
```

**- I believe the problem may lies with the get method cause it seems that I cannot properly access the user_id/reset_token in the URL?**

...localhost/example/reset_pass.php?user_id=xx&reset_token=xxxxxxxxx

- I am getting undefined variable at user_id
- Anyone knows if that the problem(s) cause my password validation also does not work?

Comment: So user id is stored in $userid , so you need to use that variable in the WHERE clause. Updated code: `WHERE user_id = " . $userid`

Comment: you mean like where user_id = ". $userid ." cause Im pretty sure i already try it, will re-try again

Comment: You don't need closing double quotes. you can replace last line as `."WHERE user_id= " . $userid;`

Comment: Still get Undefined variable: userid even with $sql= "UPDATE users SET password_hashcode='$newpass_hash', reset_allocated_time=NULL, reset_token=NULL WHERE user_id= " . $userid;

Comment: As has been mentioned countless times before, you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). It avoids these types of quoting issues, and avoids SQL injection attacks, like you're vulnerable to.

Comment: dont you see a prepare statement below $result_newpass = $heidisql->prepare($sql);

Comment: To get more help, you need to give us the exact error messages you get.

Answer (score 0):

When using prepared statements you don't actually include the values in the statement. Instead you use placeholders, and bind the values later.

Change:

```
$req = $heidisql->prepare(
  "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id='$userid' 
   AND reset_token='$reset_token' "
);
$req->execute($userid, $reset_token );
```

To:

```
$req = $heidisql->prepare(
  "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=:id 
   AND reset_token=:token "
);
$req->execute([':id'=>$userid, ':token'=>$reset_token]);
```

[See the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

Further down, you have:

```
$newpassword = escape_data($_POST['new_pass']);
$newpass_hash = password_hash($newpassword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

It's probably a bad idea to change the password (escape) before hashing it. Just hash it; the result will be safe to use. Changing it runs the risk of the user's true password not being recognized if your escape function changes in the future.

Further down you should change:

```
$sql= "UPDATE users SET password_hashcode='$newpass_hash',"
    . "reset_allocated_time=NULL, reset_token=NULL "
    . "WHERE user_id=".$user['user_id']." "; //<- error here

$result_newpass = $heidisql->prepare($sql);

$result_newpass->execute();
```

To:

```
$sql= "UPDATE users SET password_hashcode=:newpass,"
    . "reset_allocated_time=NULL, reset_token=NULL "
    . "WHERE user_id=:id"; //<- error here

$result_newpass = $heidisql->prepare($sql);

$result_newpass->execute([':newpass'=>$newpass_hash, ':id'=>$userid]);
```

Comment: Even if i put both of the sql like that it still did not work

Comment: @JohnLaimuin I made an edit. In the last query, use `$userid` instead of `$user['user_id']`

Comment: I'm getting the echo msg but there still getting the error Undefined variable: userid $result_newpass->execute([':newpass'=>$newpass_hash, ':user_id'=>$userid]); my id field is name user_id

Comment: @JohnLaimuin You set `$userid` near the top of the script with `$userid = $_GET['user_id'];` and you use it in the first query, so how can it be undefined?

Comment: My send msg linkwas like that...maybe that the problem? $message .= "<a href=' http://localhost/exemple/reset_pass.php?user_id=".$user['user_id']."&reset_token=".$new_hashtoken. " '> Click Here to enter new Password</a>"; //user_id=".$user['user_id']."

Comment: Do you know if the problem may lies with the get method cause it may seems I cannot properly get the user_id and/or the reset_token with it and thus that may be why the where statement does not work but if I put like that directly (where user_id = 10) it works!?

Answer (score 0):

Update this `$sql` from here:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET 
        password_hashcode = '$newpass_hash', 
        reset_allocated_time = NULL, 
        reset_token = NULL 
        WHERE user_id = '$user['user_id']'";
```